# How to use “short”

Tags: construction

> The supplier sent my raw material 250 kg short.

> You paid your debt a hundred dollars short.

Is the use of “short” grammatically correct? I mean can these sentence be understood by a native speaker?

Comment: yes to both questions

Answer (score 1):

They are *almost* right, but not quite. They would be understood, but they are not idiomatic.

"Short" is used as an adjective to describe a thing that is not adequate in quantity. In both your examples, it appears as if you are using it as an adverb - in example 1 you effectively say it was *sent short*, and in example 2 you say it was *paid short*.

They should really be:

- The raw materials sent by the supplier were 250 kg short.
- The payment for your debt was a hundred dollars short.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those sentences are both grammatically correct and would be commonly understood by a native speaker in the USA at least.

You could also use some variations of this if you wanted to:

> The supplier shorted me 250 kg in the latest shipment.
>
> Your payment is one hundred dollars short of what you owe me.

But I don't believe I could say that my suggestions are any better or clearer than what you wrote.

Comment: I disagree a bit; while the original sentences are *understandable*, as a US native speaker I find them odd and non-fluent, particularly the first one, and marking the speaker as not native.